# Can't install any plugin on a multisite Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I've been banging my head of this problem for days and can't find a solution online.

I have a multisite Wordpress that works except I can't install any plugin.
I know the plugins are fine as I use them all the time on my different websites, so the problem doesn't come from them.

I am familiar with multisites, so I already know where to upload the plugins and how to activate them on the network.

Things I've tried :

- Install the plugins through the default interface : it installs fine but then I get a missing header error when trying to activate. The plugin headers are however correct (checked with FTP)
- Upload the plugin as a zip : I get a "couldn't move file to wp-content/uploads/2020/07" error.
- Upload the plugin through FTP : installation is ok, but I can't find the plugin in the plugin list afterwards therefore I can't activate it
- Check php files for code injection : I did not notice anything wrong

The existing installed plugins are all working.
wp-content/plugins permission is 705, tried 755 to no avail.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Kind of a dumb answer, but have you checked / altered the plugins showed per page in the wp-admin/plugins.php? Another thing: the missing header error often leads to a mistake made in functions file. Try to activate a default theme an reinstalling the plugin

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the end I restored my database and FTP server to last week, and it works now. Must have been a corrupted file as you state.